# Is there a way to override all the viewcontroller listeners in ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs, event-handling, extjs6.2

Version ExtJs - 6.2.1
Considering the sample code specified below, i'm curious to know if there is a better approach for implementing where i can handle some checks.

```
Ext.define('MainApp.view.main.MainController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    ...    
    listen: {
        controller: {
            // listen to some components events
            'componentController':{
                'event1': 'onEvent1',
                'event2': 'onEvent2'
            }
        }
    },

    onEvent1: function(){

        // can i avoid this and do something better ??
        this.commonEventHandlingChecks();

        // event 1 handling logic
    },

    onEvent2: function(){

        // can i avoid this and do something better ??
        this.commonEventHandlingChecks();

        // event 2 handling logic
    },

    commonEventHandlingChecks: function(){
       // some logic to do some custom validations      
    }

});
```

Instead of calling the method "commonEventHandlingChecks" on each and every listener i have in my controller, is there a better way to do all the common event handling checks. Probably by overriding some methods in the controller or Ext.util.Event

Answer (score 1):

`Ext.Mixin` does have a `mixinConfig` `before` API that can add a function on the mixin and execute it. If that returns `false` then it won't execute the function is was put before. This is documented in the class description [here (link to the 6.2.1 version since you said you were using it)](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.Mixin.html).

That would work except the mixin would have to know what methods on the class it's being mixed into need to be protected. This wouldn't scale very well if you were wanting to use a mixin in different classes. For this, I would do something a little more advanced but keep the same functionality as the `before` API gives you. This mixin would look like:

```
Ext.define('MyAuthMixin', {
    extend: 'Ext.Mixin',

    onClassMixedIn: function (targetClass) {
        const proto = targetClass.prototype
        const config = proto.config
        const protectedMethods = config.protectedMethods || proto.protectedMethods
        // change this method name if you want something else
        const checkAuth = this.prototype.checkAuth

        if (protectedMethods) {
            Ext.Object.each(protectedMethods, function (key, value) {
                if (value && proto[ key ]) {
                    targetClass.addMember(key, function () {

                        // execute the checkAuth methods
                        // change this variable to change the method name
                        if (checkAuth.apply(this, arguments) !== false) {
                            return this.callParent(arguments);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    },

    checkAuth: function () {
        // return false to stop calling
        return !!MyApp.$user
    }
})
```

Don't be scared by that `onClassMixedIn` function. Basically it's putting the `checkAuth` method before the method it's being told to protect and if you return `false` in the `checkAuth` then it will not execute that protected method.

For an example of how to use it and see it in action, I have created this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2ian). The implementation in classes would be this part:

```
mixins: [
    'MyAuthMixin'
],

config: {
    // put in a config object so subclass and superclass merging
    // which is also why it's an object as a subclass can disable
    // a protected method
    protectedMethods: {
        'onEvent1': true,
        'onEvent2': true
    }
},
```

To not protect a method, you can leave it out or set it to `false`. Reason for setting to `false` would simply be a subclass could disable the check if it extends a class that has it turned on. This mixin will work for **any** class, not just a controller. It can be a component or singleton or store, any.